# How can i ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory with Log.txt in c#

Tags: c#

My code:

```
public static string Source = @"\\192.168.181.1\Z$\z";

public static string Destination = @"\\192.168.181.1\Z$\z_rar\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");

public static string Extension = @".zip";


private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (File.Exists(Destination + Extension))
        try
        {
            File.Delete(Destination + Extension);
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Source, Destination + Extension, CompressionLevel.NoCompression, false);
            // here: zipped file details in txt file
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    else
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Source, Destination + Extension, CompressionLevel.NoCompression, false);
}
```

How can i create zipped files details save to zipfilename_log.txt file (line by line) in same directory after zipfile.createfromdirectory ?

Comment: What kind of information do you want this "log file" to contain?

Comment: @Sal
Like this in txt log file
1.pdf - - zip success
A.exe - - zip failed

Comment: ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory will either succeed for all files in the folder or fail for all. Making a log file for each zipped entry doesn't really make much sense. Either way, you need to either read the file names before you zip or afterwards and simply write it to a text file.

Comment: Yup it's all or nothing unless you read them in as streams one by one. In case you do want to log all files you might as well use a shell command to list the directory contents: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "dir " + Source + " > " + Destination + "_log.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the below code:

```
        public static string Source = @"\\192.168.1.11\Z$\z";

        public static string Destination = @"\\192.168.1.11\Z$\z_rar\";

        public static string NameFormat = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd");

        public static string Extension = @".zip";

        public static string LogFilePath = Destination + NameFormat + "_log.txt";


        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.Delete(Destination + NameFormat + Extension);
            File.Delete(LogFilePath);

            try
            {
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(Source, Destination + NameFormat + Extension,
                    CompressionLevel.NoCompression, false);

                var fileListBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                using (var za = ZipFile.OpenRead(Destination + NameFormat + Extension))
                {
                    foreach (var zae in za.Entries) fileListBuilder.AppendLine(zae.FullName);
                }


                File.WriteAllText(LogFilePath, fileListBuilder.ToString());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(LogFilePath, e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Output:

1. file1.exe
2. file5.exe
3. Folder1
4. Folder2\file3.pdf
5. Folder2\file4.msi

Thanks to everyone who replies.